# How to determine which preference file lock a Firefox config option

Tags: firefox, proxy, about-config

On a Windows 7 computer, My Firefox network.proxy.type is locked so I cannot modify it
When looking at **C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\default/prefs/localsettings.js** there are only 2 lines:

> pref("general.config.obscure_value", 0);
>
> pref("general.config.filename", "config.cfg");

Then when looking at config.cfg there is no line looking like

> lockPref("network.proxy.type", 5);

and when I try to add my own preference with an other value

> pref("network.proxy.type", 2);
> I see in firefox that the preference is locked and don't take my value in account.

I also looked inside about:support to determine my profile directory and looked in every .cfg and .js files but still no lockPref that could explain why network.proxy.type is locked

Is there a way to know from which configuration file the lock is coming ?
During my web search I found a lot of pages explaining how to lock some options etc but nothing on how to understand why an option is locked

Thanks by advance for your help

Comment: What do you mean lock? Have you tried rebooting the computer if it's a file write lock?

Comment: I've seen recommendations to back up your profile folder and do a clean install of Firefox, then copy back the settings by hand (import bookmarks, copy over addons, set config values manually)

Comment: @user1306322 when you go on about:config you have the list of all firefox options and for each of them you have a status saying modified, default and this one is locked. Contrary to the others I cannot modify its value.

Comment: @user1306322 yes I have try to reboot my PC but not yet try to backup my profil and installation

Answer (score 1):

If you're in an enterprise Windows environment, it's possible that the setting has been enforced using a [Group Policy Object](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enforcing-policies-firefox-enterprise) rather than through config files.

If so, you should be able to dig up the the relevant setting from somewhere around `HKLM\Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox\Proxy` in the Windows Registry.

If you want an approach to modifying the value that's GPO resistant, note that it's possible (in 60.6.1esr) to trick Firefox into not making use of the registry values by modifying the binary `Mozilla Firefox/browser/omni.ja` accordingly (just search for `network.proxy.type`). Note also that modifying it too much (e.g. changing its length) will just cause Firefox to crash when opened.

Comment: Hi, very interesting answer thanks !
In the meantime the lock disappear (and I don't know why) but your information is very valuable and could be useful in the future
In any case I`m still interested by a kind of verbose mode in firefox that would detaill the checks and indicate at which level the lock occur

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Firefox
2. Navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox
3. Modify the mozilla.cfg file.
4. Remove any LockPref you no longer want.
5. Save As to Desktop.
6. Replace old mozilla.cfg with your new mozilla.cfg file
7. Restart Firefox

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I don't have any **mozilla.cfg** file in folder **C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox**